# Does the "given" word serve any purpose?

Tags: testing, spock

As far as I can tell, the expression `given:` (starting the "given" block) does nothing at all in Spock tests and they function exactly the same if you just omit it.

Does anyone know different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Spock [documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/spock_primer.html#_given_blocks),

> The `given` block is where you do any setup work for the feature that you are describing. It may not be preceded by other blocks, and may not be repeated. A `given` block doesn’t have any special semantics. The `given:` label is optional and may be omitted, resulting in an *implicit* `given` block. Originally, the alias `setup:` was the preferred block name, but using `given:` often leads to a more readable feature method description (see [Specifications as Documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/spock_primer.html#specifications_as_documentation)).

So, ultimately yes, it functions just the same if you omit it, because Spock implicitly puts the label there anyway; but making the `given` label explicit can help to document your tests.